# doFirst on tasks of Type Test fails to run

Tags: groovy, gradle

```
task transform(type: Test) {
    doFirst {
        println 'doFirst'
    }

    doLast {
        println 'doLast'
    }
}
```

this simply doesnt work , what is the correct usage

Comment: Check if the `testClassesDir` is set to valid directory.

Comment: gradle skips the test task if it does not find any test to run.

Comment: I got that, it always said UPTODATE and never ran that test however i tried setting outputs.upToDateWhen { false }, but it dint work ,

Comment: but what is the issue here ? If you just want to println something while gradle build or test use simple function. What are you trying to reach ?